# oracle 11g sql how MAX() works for varchar

Tags: sql, oracle11g, max, varchar

I have these values stored as `Varchar`:

```
00
0
NEE-01
LAH-01
```

how is MAX() function determining which is "more" MAX()? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The higher value is determined by the alphabetic sorting based on the collation. `L` comes before `N` so, `NEE-01` would be the "max" for the given data and `LAH-01` would be the "min".

It's the same rule that is applied if you use `order by some_varchar_column`

[As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF51038)

> Character values are compared on the basis of two measures:
>
> - Binary or linguistic sorting
> - Blank-padded or nonpadded comparison semantics

And then further down:

> In binary comparison, which is the default, Oracle compares character strings according to the concatenated value **of the numeric codes of the characters in the database character set**. One character is greater than another if it has a greater numeric value than the other in the character set. Oracle considers blanks to be less than any character, which is true in most character sets

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

So with the default binary comparison the ASCII values of the characters are taken into account. Which also means that uppercase characters are considered "higher" then lowercase characters.

Comment: Perhaps comment on lowercase vs. uppercase.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I have a little bit updated my question, because at first I thought 0 is obvious for me, but the more I know, the less I'm sure about anything :) Can you please check it? Thank you!

Comment: @user2511599 `0` as a smaller ASCII value then `a` so it's sorted before all "regular" characters

Answer (score 0):

Due to **alphabetic sorting**. For eg: 1. A, 2. B ... Z. 26
Higher value is determined.
Eg:
Max(col1) and Col1:

XABC
XYZY

**Results**:
XYZY
XABC